# Is it possible to get the result from LINQ GROUP BY into the IEnumerable List

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, ienumerable

I have the following two models

```
public class DepotDeptMapModel
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public List<DeptModel> subs { get; set; }
}
public class DeptModel
{
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the given LINQ query to get the result

```
var list = goContext.goDepartmentWorkTime.
            GroupBy(d => new { d.DepotID, d.Depot.DepotName })
        .Select(g => new
        {
            id = g.Key.DepotID,
            title = g.Key.DepotName,
            subs = g.Select(dd => new
            {
                id = dd.DepotID + "." + dd.DepartmentID,
                title = dd.Depot.DepotNo + "." + dd.Department.DepartmentName
            })
        });
```

Is it possible to get the query result into the list model

```
List<DepotDeptMapModel>  deptList
```

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: Sure. All you have to do is use more `.Select()` calls like you already did in your code. Can you explain where exactly you are stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the query result into the list model `List<DepotDeptMapModel> deptList`?

Sure, and it is quite easy if your classes are simple POCOs (= have only get/set properties). All you have to do is change your Select:

```
.Select(g => new {...
```

into:

```
.Select(g => new DepotDeptMapModel {...
```

Below the full query, slightly optimized: the Select is done in the GroupBy using parameter resultSelector:

```
List<DepotDeptMapModel> deptList = goContext.goDepartmentWorkTime.GroupBy(

    // parameter keySelector: make groups of departments with same key:
    department => new DepotDeptMapModel
    {
        department.DepotID,
        department.Depot.DepotName,
    })

    // parameter ResultSelector, take each key and all departments with this key
    // to make one new DepotDeptMapModel 
    (key, departmentsWithThisKey) => new
    {
        id = key.DepotID,
        title = key.DepotName,
        
        subs = departmentsWithThisKey.Select(department => new DeptModel
        {
            id = department.DepotID + "." + department.DepartmentID,
            title = department.Depot.DepotNo + "." + department.Department.DepartmentName
        })
        .ToList(),
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use your actual types in your `new` calls instead of anonymous types. However, since you want to do that on the client and not part of the database statement, you have to tell your context to switch over control to the client at a certain point, which is what the `.AsEnumerable()` does.

```
var list = goContext.goDepartmentWorkTime
                    .GroupBy(d => new { d.DepotID, d.Depot.DepotName })
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(g => new DepotDeptMapModel
                                 {
                                     id = g.Key.DepotID,
                                     title = g.Key.DepotName,
                                     subs = g.Select(dd => new DeptModel
                                                           {
                                                                id = dd.DepotID + "." + dd.DepartmentID,
                                                                title = dd.Depot.DepotNo + "." + dd.Department.DepartmentName
                                                           })
                                 });
```